# Units of the derivative and finding unknown values

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am having trouble understanding the following problem:
The fuel efficiency of car *E(s)*, miles per gallon, is a function of the speed of the car *s*, in miles per hour. Suppose that *E(60)* = 40 and *E′(60)* = -0.7.

a) What are the units of *E′(s)*?

b) Let *C(s)* be the fuel consumption, in gallons per mile, of the car when it is driving *s* miles per hour. Find a formula for *C(s)* in terms of *E(s)*. Calculate *C′(60)*

c) Let *R(s)*, be the rate the car burns fuel, in gallons per hour, when the car is driving *s* miles per hour. Find a formula for R(s) in terms of E(s). Calculate *R′(60)*.

I believe that the answer to a could be "mpg/mph" because that would be the units of y over the units of x when calculating the units of the derivative. For the next two questions, I don't know where to start.

Comment: For the first part the units may also be written hours per gallon. In a sense, this is giving you an instantaneous measure of how long a gallon of fuel will last if the current state of the car were extrapolated.

Answer (score 0):

a) You are right

b) gallons per mile is the inverse of miles per gallon:$$C=\frac 1E$$ For the derivative $$C'=-\frac{E'}{E^2}$$

c) $R$ is measured in gallons per hour. You can get this from gallons per mile, multiplied with miles per hour.

Can you finish?

Comment: Can you explain how you got the derivative for b)? Also, for c), because gph=gpm(mph), a possible formula could be *R′(s)=C(s)*s*, right? So, the formula for c) would be *R′(s)=(1/E(s))*s*?

Comment: $$C'(s)=\frac{dC(s)}{ds}=\frac{d\frac1{E(s)}}{ds}=\frac{d\frac 1E}{dE}\frac{dE}{ds}=-\frac1{E^2}E'$$

Comment: For part c, you need to write the formula for $R$ in terms of $E$ and $s$, and take the derivative with respect to $s$